# Cannot map function in view model with json data knockout mapping

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

My viewmodel is like this:

```
var viewModel = function(){
var self = this;
self.title = ko.observable('Hello World');
self.rows = ko.observableArray();

self.on_click = function(){
    alert('Hello World');
    var data = [
        {
            id : 1,
            x : 1,
            y : 2,
            z : 3,
        },
        {
            id : 2,
            x : 4,
            y : 5,
            z : 6,
        },
        {
            id : 3,
            x : 7,
            y : 8,
            z : 9,
        }
    ];
    self.rows(ko.unwrap(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModelRow)));
    alert(self.rows());

};
};

var viewModelRow = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable();
    self.x = ko.observable();
    self.y = ko.observable();
    self.z = ko.observable();
    self.mthd = function(){
        alert('Just Clicked');
    };
};
vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

My html is like this:

```
<body>
<h1 data-bind="text:title"></h1>
<div data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td data-bind="text : id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: x"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: y"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: z"></td>
            <td><button type="button" data-bind="click: mthd">btn</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: on_click">button</button>
</body>
```

When mapping is performed with data on **viewModelRow** view model then it throws the error saying

```
ReferenceError: mthd is not defined
```

I want all json data mapping with **viewModelRow** along with method named *mthd* define in **viewModelRow**.
Please help. *JSFIDDLE LINK*: http://jsfiddle.net/enabqm3d/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the mapping plugin in the wrong way. The `fromJS` function takes three arguments:

```
fromJS(data, mappingDefinition, mappingTarget);
```

The `mappingDefinition` defines the rules that should be executed during the mapping, for example, to create certain objects from the data, as shown here:

```js
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.title = ko.observable('Hello World');
    self.rows = ko.observableArray();
    self.init = function(){
        var data = {
            rows: [
                {id : 1, x : 1, y : 2, z : 3,},
                {id : 2, x : 4, y : 5, z : 6,},
                {id : 3, x : 7, y : 8, z : 9,}
            ]
        };

        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
            rows: {
                create: function (options) {
                    return new ViewModelRow(options.data);
                }
            }
        }, self);
    };
};

var ViewModelRow = function(data){
    var self = this;

    // think whether these properties really need to be observable
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.x = ko.observable(data.x);
    self.y = ko.observable(data.y);
    self.z = ko.observable(data.z);
    self.mthd = function(){
        alert('Just clicked ' + self.id() );
    };
};

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<h1 data-bind="text:title"></h1>

<div data-bind="foreach: rows">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: x"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: y"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: z"></td>
      <td><button type="button" data-bind="click: mthd">btn</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button type="button" data-bind="click: init">init viewmodel</button>
```

Read through [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), it's not even a lot to read.

Answer (score 1):

As scenario looks simple you can achieve it using `.arrayMap` mapping to the function which having observables

**viewModel:**

```
var viewModelRow = function (param) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(param.id);
    self.x = ko.observable(param.x);
    self.y = ko.observable(param.y);
    self.z = ko.observable(param.z);
    self.mthd = function () {
        alert('im clicked')
    };
};

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable('Hello World');
    self.rows = ko.observableArray();
    self.on_click = function () {
        var converted = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (item) {
            return new viewModelRow(item); // key part here
        })
        self.rows(converted); // assigning after converting everything into observables
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

working fiddle up **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/enabqm3d/7/)**

Comment: suggesting a pragmatic approach, +1